# 'context.Request' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, httpcontext

I am trying to use access HTTPContext inside Global.asax Application_Start() event.

```
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            if (context.Request != null) //Getting error here
            {
                  .....
            }
        }
```

When accessing `context.Request` I am getting `'context.Request' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'` exception.

In this case `context.Request` is not null but its throwing exception.

I used following code to identify if the `Request` property exists:

```
context.GetType().GetProperty("Request");
```

**And I got following response.**

```
{System.Web.HttpRequest Request}
    Attributes: None
    CanRead: true
    CanWrite: false
    CustomAttributes: Count = 0
    DeclaringType: {Name = "HttpContext" FullName = "System.Web.HttpContext"}
    GetMethod: {System.Web.HttpRequest get_Request()}
    IsSpecialName: false
    MemberType: Property
    MetadataToken: 385876876
    Module: {System.Web.dll}
    Name: "Request"
    PropertyType: {Name = "HttpRequest" FullName = "System.Web.HttpRequest"}
    ReflectedType: {Name = "HttpContext" FullName = "System.Web.HttpContext"}
    SetMethod: null

I am not sure how to confirm if context.Request exists and is not null ?
```

Comment: This can indicate that you're running in under IIS 7 in Integrated mode. Also, which event are you responding to?

Comment: @ScottHannen: I am using `Application_Start()` event. inside that, I am using `HTTPContext.Current.Request` to extract caller agent.

Comment: which property are you trying to read from the request context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.request):

> ASP.NET will throw an exception if you try to use this property when the HttpRequest object is not available. For example, this would be true in the Application_Start method of the Global.asax file, or in a method that is called from the Application_Start method. At that time no HTTP request has been created yet.

`Application_Start` isn't meant to handle a specific request, so you would need to move what you're doing into the handler for a different event, like `BeginRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
   private static HttpRequest initialRequest;

   static Global()
   {
      initialRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;       
   }

   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //access the initial request here

    }
```

You can use here Application_Start event .The static type is created with a request in its HTTPContext, allowing you to store it and reuse it immediately in the Application_Start event.